# Scaling the axes in ListDesnsityPlot

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have a matrix of size 800x600 in which each value is basically z value. This matrix is stored in text file. I want to import the file in Mathematica and plot it as DensityPlot using ListDensityPlot. In doing so, I am able to plot the data but the x and y axis scale as 0 to 800 and 0 to 600 respectively indicating basically indices of the values stored in the matrix. But in reality I want to scale both x and y axis lets say x ranges from 0 to 4 and y ranges from 0 to 3. In other words I want to  keep full scale of the plot with all the data while my frame ticks on x and y axis scaled from 0 to 4 and 0 to 3 respectively.

For example, when I import the data (here my data is matrix of size 301x201)and plot it, it looks this, here basically it takes x and y axis tick values as data indices in the matrix

[image: Plot from importing the data]

But actually, in my plot I want to change the axis tick values like this way keeping everything else as it is

[image: Plot by evaluating the function]

Comment: Please give us a sample of what your data might look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListDensityPlot` has an option called `DataRange` that will scale the axis for you.

Here is some synthetic data that represents a 800 x 600 array of z-values.

```
data = Table[Sin[3 i/800 + (3 j/600)^2], {j, 1, 600}, {i, 1, 800}];
```

The default plot:

```
ListDensityPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now use the `DataRange` option:

```
ListDensityPlot[data, DataRange -> {{0, 4}, {0, 3}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]